# Red and orange streaks leaking down my concrete basement wall, and is this a major concern?

Tags: concrete, basement, foundation, waterproofing

I discovered a large number of streaks running down the interior of my basement foundation wall in a storage closet. It looks like mildew or perhaps iron ochre. The wall abuts a patio with paver stones and a hose bib connection. There is also red liquid (dried) pooling on the basement closet floor.

[image]

[image]

I’ve included a few pictures. Is this something to be concerned about? Where could it be coming from and does this mean I have water infiltration below the soil line of my foundation? This is the only wall this is occurring on. Also, any idea what the white caps on the interior wall are for? Is that leftover from the foundation pour or a previous inspection?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes it is major concern

Comment: Why is it a major concern? What’s the cause and what’s the likely remediation needed? Any thoughts?

Comment: do you have a drain on the outside around foundation? over time the wood exposed to the water will rot

Comment: Not that I’m aware of. We have landscaping that’s graded away from the foundation but we get a ton of water from rains. The only drains I’ve located on property are gutter rain spout drains above that wall that run away from foundation for some distance through underground pvc pipes. The other drain is a standard sump but other side of basement.

Comment: take some pictures of the outside of this concrete wall where it joins with your framing.  How high above ground is the top of the concrete?  do you have rainscreen?

Comment: do you wash the patio with a water sprayer?

Comment: Is the patio surface higher than the top of the concrete wall?

Comment: this can not be investigated from inside, go and dig a hole next to the foundation and see

Comment: We do wash the patio with a sprayer but not this year though. I’ll get a few pictures of the outside soon. Not sure what a rainsceen is with regards to concrete walls. I’ll have to look that one up and reply back. As far as I can tell the patio surface is lower than the concrete wall. The picture I put up has a hose bib copper line at the top right and the paver stones are set 2-3 feet below the hose connection. I’d assume that this makes the concrete similarly high above the patio.